# Monitors go blank but still emitting light when display turned off; actually go black when in suspend

Tags: display, suspend

I'm using ElementaryOS and I have it set to "Turn off display when inactive for" 5 minutes.

When this triggers, the connected monitors will say there is no HDMI signal, but then they will both go blank without actually turning off. What I mean is they go black but seem to be emitting a full screen full of black light. You can see it in the dark.

When I actually put my OS into suspend mode, by choosing Suspend, the monitors will actually turn off and stop emitting light.

How can I get "turn display off" to also get the monitors to turn off and stop emitting light?

There are two different monitors connected, one Asus and one Dell.